# CSS3 transitions inconsistent across FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have created a CSS3 animation that does not behave consistently across the different browsers.  Here is a quick and dirty overview, and I have included a JSFiddle link at the end.

Here is the CSS:

```
.cloned_object {
   position:absolute;
   background-color:white;
   width: 700px;
   height: 640px;
   margin: 0; /*for centering purposes*/
   -webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
   -moz-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
   -ms-transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s ;
   transition: width 1s, height 1s, top 1s, left 1s, margin 1s;
}
```

and the JS function:

```
$('.content_cell').on('click', function(event) {
        // if the user is on a browser older then IE9
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0,1)<10) {
            var $clonedElement = $( this ).clone(true).attr('class','cloned_object content_cell').appendTo('#mainContentTable');
            $clonedElement.css({left:$(this).position().left, 
                                top:$(this).position().top, 
                                opacity:1.0}) ;

            selectedPos = $(this).position();

            var currentPos = $('#invitedToChatCell').position();

            $clonedElement.animate({
                height:640, width:700, 
                //position:'absolute', 
                left:currentPos.left, 
                top:currentPos.top, 
                opacity:1.0 
            }, 500, function(){ $('.cloned_object > ul').toggle(); });

        } else {
            var currentPos = $('#invitedToChatCell').position();

            var $clonedElement = $( this ).clone(true).attr('class', 'content_cell').appendTo('#mainContentTable');
            $clonedElement.css({left:$(this).position().left, 
                                top:$(this).position().top}) ;

            $clonedElement.addClass('cloned_object');               
            $clonedElement.css({'margin-left':-$(this).position().left+125,
                                'margin-top':-$(this).position().top,
                                }) ;

            selectedPos = $(this).position();           

            $('.cloned_object > ul').toggle();
        }                   

        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

I am really at a loss as to why it would be different across browsers.  I was hoping someone could enlighten me as to what is going on...

[Here is the jsFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/neK8g/4/)  If you run it in both browsers, you will see the animation position is different.  In FF, it looks like the box grows, that is what I  want.  In chrome it's very strange...

Comment: Between FF10 and Chrome on Linux it looks exactly the same. *edit* wait I see; it's like it starts from the left in Chrome ...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transitions explicitly request that the "top" and "left" be animated.  They've got to start from somewhere, so they start from zero.  It's a weird case because the "cloned-element" style is not what's giving the element the "top" and "left" values, it's your code which puts them straight on the element.

You're *also* animating the margin, however; Chrome doesn't seem to pay much attention to that. If I take the "top" and "left" properties out of the transition, it makes it act a little more like Firefox.

The concept of applying a transition to an element at the same time it comes into existence is a little confusing to me.  I hope somebody comes along and provides a better answer.

Comment: I also just stumbled across this fact on my own. :)  Basically, I removed the animations to the top and left, and it worked perfectly.  What was happening, like you said, was it was applying the animations to the top and left.  I did not want these animated, I just wanted it moved to the correct position for the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Hopefully that helps with some confusion someone has down the road.  :)